# insert image to .doc file in android Java using Apache POI

Tags: java, android, apache, apache-poi

I'm trying to write images to .doc file in android. I've searched a lot and I couldn't find any help to do that. A hint which I've got so for is Apache POI library. I've studied it too and I couldn't get any method describing my problem. I know how to create that file and here is the code to do that from its documentation

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;

public class CreateDocument 
{
   public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception 
   {
   //Blank Document
   XWPFDocument document= new XWPFDocument(); 
   //Write the Document in file system
   FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(
   new File("createdocument.docx"));
   document.write(out);
   out.close();

   }
```

}

But how i can insert images into that file. please help. any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Apache POI website provides example for this. http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/SimpleImages.java

Answer (score 0):

First of all decide what you want .doc or .docx ( know the difference )
You asked question for .doc format but your code says .docx (XWPFDocument for .docx)

As of now there is no way of adding an image into .doc using HWPF ( please do correct me if I am wrong).

If looking for .docx (XWPF) then https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/

look for addPicture in  XWPFDocument and  XWPFRun
and examples for same 
http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/ooxml/testcases/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/